# wsdl java classes generation to specific package

Tags: java, wsdl

Which option I have to use in wsimport tool to generate wsdl based java classes in selected package?

Suppose that I have wsdl file, I want to run wsimport on that to generate classes to selected package.

Answer (score 0):

-p

> Specifying a target package via this command-line option, overrides any wsdl and schema binding customization for package name and the default package name algorithm defined in the specification

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Comment: naybe a full command line would be more appropriate. but good research!